# show html output in textarea instead of HTML code

Tags: javascript, textarea

If I have a textarea including some HTML code, how can I write a JavaScript function to show the HTML output instead of HTML code itself, for example:

```
<textarea id="mytextarea">
<table border=1><tr><td>cellone</td>td>celltwo</td></tr></table
</textarea>
<input type=button onclick="HTMLoutput();"/>

<script>
HTMLoutput()
{
//Code to show html output instead of html code in textarea
}
</script>
```

How can I do this? What is the suggested code to write inside the HTMLoutput()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I show HTML formatting inside a textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785607/how-can-i-show-html-formatting-inside-a-textarea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to convert the the html code to a formated html you need to do:

```
$('resultDiv').append($('<div/>').html($('.txtArea').val()+"<br>");
```

here's [an example](http://jsbin.com/oBiBoBE/10/edit?html,output) that use div with contentEditable set to true.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking how to take some HTML and display its rendered result in your document.

That's exactly what the `innerHTML` property does.
Simply pick a DOM element to display the result in, and set its `innerHTML` to the HTML to display.

Comment: i want to build an editor and to show the rendered result inside the textarea itself as a preview

Comment: @user2888402: `<textarea>` can only show plain text.  You can use CSS to show a preview on top of the textbox.

Comment: thanks @Slaks can you please give me an example how to do this using CSS?